# SwipeRefreshLayout conflict with listview when scroll down?

Tags: android

I used this [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/05/android-swipe-down-to-refresh-listview-tutorial/)
, it works fine , but when I scroll down the listview , it call SwipeRefreshLayout Refresh So I can't scroll down the listview ??

Answer (score 0):

override this method of SwipeRefreshLayout Class:

```
@Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        return ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(myListView, -1);
    }
```